# Как найти в предложении слова, НЕ содержащие символ?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Как найти в предложении все слова, НЕ содержащие символ "@", с помощью регулярного выражения?

язык php или javascript

Comment: язык программирования? Сами пробовали что нибудь сделать?

Comment: php javascript, да пробовал, содержащие символ могу найти, а условие когда не содержит не получалось

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант для PHP: `/((?<=\s|^)[^@ ]+(?=\s|$))/g` (используется просмотр вперёд и назад для выделения слова: ?= и ?<=)

Comment: в JavaScript точной такой же паттерн, и в .NET паттерн такой же, но только параметры (т.е. / и /g) надо убрать.

Comment: Спасибо! как раз то что надо!

Comment: @ДмитрийПортнов: если ответ решает вашу задачу, вы можете его отметить как верный – галочка слева от вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

> все слова НЕ содержащие символ "@"

Если проверяете отдельные слова, то так:

`^((?!@).)*$`

пример [тут](http://refiddle.com/2uea).

Comment: Спасибо, помогло в понимании